# Не работают cookie (PHP)

Tags: php, cookie, unix, apache2, localhost

Вот это код:

```
setcookie('Token', '1');
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Веб-сервер выводит это ПРИ СЛЕДУЮЩЕЙ ЗАГРУЗКЕ:

```
Array()
```

Cookie в браузере включены.

Comment: У меня в Chrome есть инспектор объектов. Включается он после нажатия на F12. В нем есть вкладка Sources, в моем файле index.php выводит все существующие куки. У Вас там что-то есть?

Comment: Куки после установки видны при __следующей__ загрузке страницы. Если хотите чтобы были видны сразу - __ручками__ добавьте нужный ключ в `_COOKIES`

Comment: Это он выдаёт при следующей загрузке.

Comment: Это явно не весь php-файл. Приложите нерабочий файл целиком, предварительно составив [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Цитирую [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php):

> После передачи клиенту cookie станут доступны через массив $_COOKIE
>   **при следующей загрузке страницы**.

Comment: Это он выдаёт при следующей загрузке.